# Why isn't my angular controller hitting my Web Api Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get a List of test customers from the server. I know that the Web API controller is receiving the data from the DB because I have unit/integration tests around it; however, when I try and pull the data to my angular controller I receive a 500 status code.

Angular Controller:

```
var surchargeIndex = angular.module('surchargeIndex', []);

surchargeIndex.controller('SurchargeIndexController', function ($scope, customerService) {
    $scope.customers = { Key: "", Value: "" };
    customerService.getTest($scope);
});

surchargeIndex.service('customerService', [
    '$http', function($http) {
        this.getTest = function ($scope) {
            return $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "api/Customer/GetTest",
            })
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.customers = data;
            })
            .error(function () {
                $scope.error = "Failed to load customers!";
            });
        }
    }
]);
```

Web Api:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Customer")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ICustomerService _service;

    public CustomerController(ICustomerService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    [Route("GetTest"), HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<IJsonResult> GetTest()
    {
        return _service.GetTest();
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you inspect the details of the 500 error?

Comment: @jadarnel27 It states, resource failed to load.

Comment: Could you set a breakpoint in your C# code and see if there is an exception being thrown?  I know you mentioned that you have automated tests around this code, but it could be good to just verify something is not going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Web API` doesn't allow remote connections by default.

This is called `Cross-origin resource sharing` (`CORS`).

`Web API 2.2` makes it easy to enable `CORS` by providing the `EnableCorsAttribute`.

Basic Usage

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
public class ResourcesController : ApiController
{
    ...
```

Attribute definition

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class|AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public EnableCorsAttribute(
    string origins,
    string headers,
    string methods
)
```

To enable `CORS` globally use

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("www.example.com", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
        // ...
    }
}
```

You will also need to install the CORS package from `nuget`

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Comment: So I will need to do this for each of the WebApi controllers?

Comment: No, you can register it as a global attribute if you wish. I have edited my answer to include a such example.

Comment: do I have to put the actual localhost (eventually production site) in the first parameter or can that be something random for now?

Comment: Why would CORS apply here?  From the code the OP shared, it's client code (JavaScript) making a request to a Web API controller.  I don't see anything that indicates there are cross-domain requests happening.

Comment: @jadarnel27: are you serious? JS code runs on client, Web API on server, go figure.

Comment: @Robert: you can use * to allow connections from everywhere. In order to allow AJAX requests you have to allow all.

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu Just chiming in here.. CORS and the Client-Server interaction work somewhat differently than you seem to think. It's absolutely not required to enable CORS for Javascript interaction with a WebAPI controller (or any other servicing). If that were the case, the security benefit of disallowing Cross Origin Resource-Sharing in the first place would be lost.

Comment: @Vogel612: Yes, you could use jsonp. But still, cors is much preferred.